# Apache 2.4 / PHP 5.6 (Error Loading Dynamic Libraries)

Tags: php, windows, apache

I've been having an issue with my Apache 2.4 server which I have setup on Windows 2008 R2 SP1.

When installing PHP most of my extensions are loading without fault my "extension_dir=" is set to the full path and loading a handful of modules without error, However I have a problem with the remainder of these modules.

For example:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Apache24\\php\\ext\\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Apache24\\php\\ext\\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Apache24\\php\\ext\\php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

For reference the modules do exist in the required directory.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem with same apache and php version and the same warinings...

Comment: I actually managed to resolve some of the errors I have been getting, I looked about on the net for any possible solution it appears that the dependencies for the modules are being called from the wrong folder, copying *.dll from the php directory into my apache\bin folder has resolved these issues for me.

That is excluding my ext folder of course.